# Whitelisting an email address using gmail add-ons

Tags: gmail-api, gmail-addons, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Is there any API available to whitelist a particular email adddress using gmail add-ons?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this via gmail addons ?

Comment: @HariBalaji i want to achieve through gmail api.. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail add-ons are triggered when you open a message.

In your case, the add-on should run and whitelist an incoming email. This implies that the add-on should get triggered even before you open a mail, which currently is not possible.

I hope this helps. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: The best approach for that would be creating a chrome extension using inboxSDK. Go through this https://www.inboxsdk.com/ .